# Running a script in an EC2 Linux Instance from AWS Lambda

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

Ive been looking for ways to create a lambda function that can access directly the contents of an EC2 Linux instance. My goal is to be able to call a script residing in the home directory AND pass in a variable which the script will use for processing.

Ive been looking at different ways of doing it, but I cant seem to find a concise solution.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your instance has the SSM agent running on it then your Lambda can run the [send-command](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/send-command.html).

Using the AWS-RunShellScript document your Lambda can execute a number of commands on your EC2 instance for you.

You could also [create your own document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/create-ssm-doc.html) for SSM passing in an argument for each of the variables.